# alembic - how to share functions across revisions?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

Alembic doesn't support replaceable objects like views so we often have to write a custom function in revision that executes creation of them. Is there a way to share these functions across revisions instead of copy-pasting over and over?

Answer (score 0):

After looking, you can either reference code in a separate package or use env.py. Creating your own module is probably easier